# Getting a Screenshot From A Bloomberg Terminal

Tags: vba, screenshot, bloomberg

I have a project and it requires grabbing multiple screenshots from a Bloomberg Terminal and I'd like to automate it.

This what I have so far:

```
Dim abc As Variant
Dim CUSIP As String

CUSIP = Range("A1")
ch = DDEInitiate("winblp", "bbk")

Call DDEExecute(abc, "<blp-1>" & CUSIP & " mtge<GO>")
Call DDEExecute(abc, "<blp-1> CFG<Go>")
Call DDEExecute (abc, "blp-1 <copy>")
Call DDETerminate(ch)
```

This correctly gets me to the graph I want (in this case the CFG, or Cash Flow Graph), but from this point, I am unable to figure out a screenshot method. In Bloomberg, there are a few commands, but they all require the use of a mouse. I've seen some do it before where they are able to get the requisite screenshots, but I can't figure out how.

So basically, I can use excel and VBA to get Bloomberg to pull up the correct screen, but now I just need to figure out a way to grab snipshot for the thing.

It's worth mentioning that the copy line just copies the data, not an image (which is what I was hoping for).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to send the screenshot to your personal email address and download it from there:

1. Run GRAB in `blp-1`
2. Enter your personal email address
3. Download it manually from there or use an IMAP library to do so automatically

Another option is to use a 3rd party grabbing utility that has command line options. For example, Snagit can be started with an argument that creates a screenshot: http://informationworker.ru/snagit10.en/snagit_4_technical_reference.4.35.html